# Interactive PyPlot Figure in Tkinter not registering MouseEvents

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, mouseevent, interactive

I am building an interactive Tkinter GUI wherein a blank pyplot figure and axes are drawn in the GUI along with some buttons, where the user can click, drag, and delete points to form a custom point plot. The coordinates of these points can then be printed in a particular format used as Input in a much more complex Fortran code. I have gotten almost everything to work, except for the initial interactivity of the figure/axes space. I am heavily relying on a wonderful Draggable-Plot object code I found on GitHub by user yuma-m, link below:

https://github.com/yuma-m/matplotlib-draggable-plot/blob/master/draggable_plot.py

After much tweaking of the original Draggable-Plot object I was able to get the interactive plot integrated into my GUI; HOWEVER the bug comes in when I generate the plot for the first time. After setting the correct axes bounds, and clicking 'Update Axes' for the FIRST time, the figure and plot are drawn but do NOT register any MouseEvents. My guess is that when the `event.inaxes in [self._axes]` condition is checked in the `_on_click` function, the existence/placement of `self._axes` is being blocked in some way.

The best part happens when you click the 'Update Axes' button a second time, and a new axes object is plotted directly below the first. When this occurs, the script will begin to register MouseEvents in the INITIAL plot, but will draw all corresponding points in the new SECOND plot. When I restrict the placement of the second plot in the same grid position as the first, no interactivity is registered, as I'm guessing the new axes overlaps the first.

I'm simply looking for a solution to this bizarre problem; obviously the ideal functionality of this GUI would be initial interactivity of the first generated plot, with any subsequently generated axes behaving the same. Thank you!

[Image of Two Axes state of GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRFFd.png)

```
import math
import matplotlib

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

class B2PtGen(tk.Tk): 

def __init__(self):

    root = Tk()

    root.title("B2 Inputfile Point Generator")
    root.geometry("800x800")

    app = Frame(root)
    app.grid()

    self._Xmin = -0.1
    self._Xmax = 0.1
    self._Ymin = 0
    self._Ymax = 1
    self._figure, self._axes, self._line = None, None, None
    self._dragging_point = None
    self._points = {}

    Instr = Label(app,text = "Enter ranges of X and Y axes in corresponding text boxes below, then click 'Update Axes'. \nUse plot area to draw shape of Inputfile Curve \n(Left Mouse Button to create points, Right Mouse Button to delete points). \nThen click 'Generate Point List' to create Inputfile Point List")
    Instr.grid(column=0,row=0,columnspan=4)

    Lbl1 = Label(app, text = "X min")
    Lbl1.grid(column=0,row=1)

    XminT = Entry(app, width=10)
    XminT.insert(0,'-0.1')
    XminT.grid(column=0,row=2)

    Lbl2 = Label(app, text = "X max")
    Lbl2.grid(column=1,row=1)

    XmaxT = Entry(app, width=10)
    XmaxT.insert(0,'0.1')
    XmaxT.grid(column=1,row=2)

    Lbl3 = Label(app, text = "Y min")
    Lbl3.grid(column=0,row=3)

    YminT = Entry(app, width=10)
    YminT.insert(0,'0')
    YminT.grid(column=0,row=4)

    Lbl4 = Label(app, text = "Y max")
    Lbl4.grid(column=1,row=3)

    YmaxT = Entry(app, width=10)
    YmaxT.insert(0,'1')
    YmaxT.grid(column=1,row=4)

    def clicked():
        if float(XminT.get()) < float(XmaxT.get()) and float(YminT.get()) < float(YmaxT.get()): 
            self._Xmin = float(XminT.get())
            self._Xmax = float(XmaxT.get())
            self._Ymin = float(YminT.get())
            self._Ymax = float(YmaxT.get())
            Lbl1.configure(text = "Xmin = " + XminT.get())
            Lbl2.configure(text = "Xmax = " + XmaxT.get())
            Lbl3.configure(text = "Ymin = " + YminT.get())
            Lbl4.configure(text = "Ymax = " + YmaxT.get())

            self._init_plot(app)         

        else:
            print("Input values do not form valid ranges")                  

    button1 = Button(app, command=clicked)
    button1.grid(column=2,row=2,columnspan=2)
    button1['text'] = "Update Axes"

    root.mainloop() 

def _init_plot(self, app):
    if not self._figure:
        self._figure = plt.figure(num=1)

    if not self._axes:
        print('New Axes!')
        self._axes = plt.axes()

    plt.sca(self._axes)    
    self._axes.set_xlim(self._Xmin, self._Xmax)
    self._axes.set_xlabel('Radial Distance from Separatrix (along Outer Midplane) [m]')
    self._axes.set_ylabel('Normalized Coefficient Magnitude')
    self._axes.set_ylim(self._Ymin, self._Ymax)
    self._axes.grid(b=True,which="both")
    #self._axes = axes

    self._figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self._on_click)
    self._figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self._on_release)
    self._figure.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self._on_motion)

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self._figure, app)
    canvas.show()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(columnspan=4)

def _update_plot(self):
    if not self._points:
        return
    x, y = zip(*sorted(self._points.items()))
    # Add new plot
    if not self._line:
        self._line, = self._axes.plot(x, y, "b", marker="o", markersize=5)
    # Update current plot
    else:
        self._line.set_data(x, y)
    self._figure.canvas.draw()

def _add_point(self, x, y=None):
    if isinstance(x, MouseEvent):
        x, y = float(x.xdata), float(x.ydata)
    self._points[x] = y
    return x, y

def _remove_point(self, x, _):
    if x in self._points:
        self._points.pop(x)

def _find_neighbor_point(self, event):
    u""" Find point around mouse position
    :rtype: ((int, int)|None)
    :return: (x, y) if there are any point around mouse else None
    """
    distance_threshold = 0.05*(self._Ymax - self._Ymin)
    nearest_point = None
    min_distance = math.sqrt((self._Xmax - self._Xmin)**2 + (self._Ymax - self._Ymin)**2)
    for x, y in self._points.items():
        distance = math.hypot(event.xdata - x, event.ydata - y)
        if distance < min_distance:
            min_distance = distance
            nearest_point = (x, y)
    if min_distance < distance_threshold:
        return nearest_point
    return None

def _on_click(self, event):
    u""" callback method for mouse click event
    :type event: MouseEvent
    """
    # left click
    if event.button == 1 and event.inaxes in [self._axes]:
        point = self._find_neighbor_point(event)
        if point:
            self._dragging_point = point
            self._remove_point(*point)
        else:
            self._add_point(event)
        print('You clicked!')    
        self._update_plot()
    # right click
    elif event.button == 3 and event.inaxes in [self._axes]:
        point = self._find_neighbor_point(event)
        if point:
            self._remove_point(*point)
            self._update_plot()

def _on_release(self, event):
    u""" callback method for mouse release event
    :type event: MouseEvent
    """
    if event.button == 1 and event.inaxes in [self._axes] and self._dragging_point:
        self._add_point(event)
        self._dragging_point = None
        self._update_plot()

def _on_motion(self, event):
    u""" callback method for mouse motion event
    :type event: MouseEvent
    """
    if not self._dragging_point:
        return
    self._remove_point(*self._dragging_point)
    self._dragging_point = self._add_point(event)
    self._update_plot()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    B2PtGen()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be very helpful to have an image or two of what is going wrong as well as the description.

Comment: Can you compress this to a [mcve], which does not contain any unnecessary stuff, and is runnable by itself?

Comment: I have provided an image and removed unnecessary code from the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your _init_plot() function to the following, seems to update a little better...

```
    if not self._figure:
        self._figure = plt.figure(num=1)
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self._figure, app)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(columnspan=4)

    if not self._axes:
        print('New Axes!')
        self._axes = plt.axes()

    self._axes.set_xlim(self._Xmin, self._Xmax)
    self._axes.set_xlabel('Radial Distance from Separatrix (along Outer Midplane) [m]')
    self._axes.set_ylabel('Normalized Coefficient Magnitude')
    self._axes.set_ylim(self._Ymin, self._Ymax)
    self._axes.grid(b=True,which="both")
    self._figure.sca(self._axes)

    self._figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self._on_click)
    self._figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self._on_release)
    self._figure.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self._on_motion)

    self._figure.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you, this solution makes a lot of sense in retrospect